# Replace the div content instead of add

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using XMLHttpRequest() to refresh the div in 5 minutes but it generates and add new content instead of replacing previous one.

```
<div id="pie"></div>
  <script>
  function updateScript() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  eval(xhr.responseText); 
  }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "index.js", true);
  xhr.send();
  }
  updateScript();
  setInterval(updateScript, 30 * 1000);
  </script>
```

[image: It generated new pie chart every time]

When I change `eval(xhr.responseText)` to `document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML =eval(xhr.responseText);` it replace the chart but shows some code with it.
[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to update `column1` *and* `column2`, or just `column1` based on a condition on `Name` and `column2`?

Comment: based on Column 1 I have to update column2

Comment: What is `'value'='B'` supposed to mean? that is a string comparison that cannot be true. Do you mean the existng value in `column1`? I think it would be really helpful if you edited your question with some sample input and expected output data.

Comment: value: which is inserted by user for column1

Comment: it checks condition like : A->B->C->D

Answer (score 0):

You need two values

```
 Update table_name 

 SET    column1=CASE 
        WHEN Name='abc' THEN 'xyz' 
        WHEN Name='xyz' THEN 'abc' 
    END, 
    column2=CASE 
        WHEN Name='abc' TEHN ''
        WHEN Name='xyz' THEN ='' 
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off.  I would use this version:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = CASE WHEN Name = 'abc' THEN 'xyz' ELSE 'abc' END
WHERE Name IN ('abc', 'xyz') AND column2 = '';
```

This update will only affect those records having name values of `abc` and `xyz`.  For such records, the single `CASE` expression will toggle those values.  Note that the restriction on `column2` being empty applies to the entire update, and so that can be moved to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WHERE clause to filter the table and the CASE expression like this:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = CASE Name 
                WHEN 'abc' THEN 'xyz' 
                WHEN 'xyz' THEN 'abc' 
              END,
    column2 = '' 
WHERE Name IN ('abc', 'xyz')
```